Showing that the sum of $E_k = \{f \geq k\}$ is finite for non-negative $f \in L^1$.
Consider a non-negative function $f \in L^1$ which is measurable on an arbitrary measure space. Define the sets $$ E_k = \{ f \geq k\} \, ; \, A_k = \{ k \leq f < k+1\}$$
I wish to show that the following sums are finite:
$$  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(E_k)  \, ; \, \sum_{k=1}^\infty k \mu(A_k)$$
My approach is as follows - For the first sum, consider $g_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \chi_{E_k}$, where $\chi_{A}$ denotes the characteristic function on a set $A$. Then $g_n \leq f$, so $\int g_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(E_k) \leq \int f$. Taking a limit as $n \to \infty$ and using that $f \in L^1$ then concludes the proof. For the second sum, the proof should be very similar, but instead I considered $g'_n = \sum_{k=1}^n k\chi_{A_k}$. Could I know if this proof is correct?
